# How can I encrypt/decrypt a "file" (instead of text) using cryptojs?

Tags: javascript, cordova, encryption, file-io, cryptojs

How can I encrypt/decrypt a "file" (instead of text) using cryptojs?
I want to do this inside a cordova app and using AES algorithm.
(Using crypto.js is not a requirement and any other appropriate library would be helpful)
Thanks in advance

Comment: If it works for text, why don't you try reading the file and then manipulating the text? Here's an example - http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/15/Cordova-Sample-Reading-a-text-file

Comment: The file is a zip file which contains a lot of various files.

Comment: @Mohammad What is your point? Are you asking about encrypting a zip file so that it can be decrypted by a run-of-the-mill zip application? File contents can be seen as a blob and encrypted wholly, but that approach won't work for standard-conform zip encryption.

Comment: @ArtjomB. As I mentioned I want a zip file encrypted/decrypted inside an app that is written in JS (using cordova). It's a very simple question and if you have the answer it would be so nice of you to write some code.

Comment: Maybe the solution is to first convert the file to a text string (maybe base64 format is an appropriate choice) and then use that string as the input, and for decryption, decrypting to that string and converting it to the original file.

Comment: @Mohammad, were you able to figure out a solution? I’m in exactly the same situation. Thank you 

Comment: @MartinAdams, sorry, unfortunately not.